# ERROR al conectar al Servidor de HUE.!

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose, manjaro, hive

Tengo un problema cuando estoy dentro de la web de HUE, no me carga el servidor, uso "Manjaro,Liunux".
Alguien tiene una solucion al respecto? adjunto una imagen.[image: servidor hue]